# How install python moduls via git bash on windows

Tags: python, git

First I installed Python 3.3, then I installed Git for windows. I opened git bash and want to clone pip from git hub. How to get the address which I have to type with the second command?

```
cd C:\Python33
git clone https://github.com/???
```

Which commands I have to run, if I want to install the module pip after downloading? I read this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows) but I cant decide which method I should use?

Comment: Why do you want to install it by cloning from github, instead of following [the installation instructions](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html)?

Comment: Because I want to know how to install some module if I would clone it from git hub.

Comment: But I don't understand how you can not know the address of what you want to clone.

Comment: I know this address `https://github.com/pypa/pip.git` but I was not sure if I could use it. And I dont know how exactly I should install the module after cloning. Could I go to the directory of pip and execute the setup.py via python. I do so before with some other modules,but it does not work. for example I installed a version of mongo-connector with easy_install and after I cloned a newer version from git hub and installed it but it does not replaced the files from the older version.

Comment: Use the SSH clone URL in the Git Bash ``git clone git@github.com:pypa/pip.git``